# Swift and APIs: Decoding JSON tree

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, httprequest

In my app, I have a song-searching feature where I call the Happi API (https://happi.dev/docs/music) and it will return songs with song info that matches a search keyword passed in.

Here is my code for accessing the data:

```
func getSongs(completion: @escaping(Result<[SongInfo], SongError>) -> Void) {
    
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: resourceURL) { data, _, _ in
        guard let jsonData = data else {
            completion(.failure(.noDataAvailable))
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let songResponse = try decoder.decode(SongResponse.self, from: jsonData)
            //print("decoded")
            let songInfos = songResponse.response.results
            completion(.success(songInfos))
        }catch{
            completion(.failure(.canNotProcessData))
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

the `let dataTask` portion of the code is successful, and does not return the `noDataAvailable` error. However, I do receive a `canNotProcessData` error when I go decode the JSON data, and I assuming it's because of an error in my structure, but not entirely sure. Here's my structure:

```
    struct SongResponse:Decodable {
    var response:Results
}

    struct Results:Decodable {
        var results: [SongInfo]
    }

struct SongInfo:Decodable {
    var songName:String
    var artist:String
}
```

Here are photos of my JSON tree from the API:[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuM1K.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMrsQ.png)

Essentially, all I want is to retrieve each array in the results:[] dictionary, then for each array, I want to get the values for `track` and `artist`. For example in the image there are 5 results, and for each result i want to create a song class with "track" and "artist" attributes. These song classes would be stored in an array. Please let me know how to change my code, or of an easier way to do this!

EDIT: error message:
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "response", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "response", intValue: nil) ("response").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: `print(error)` in your catch block to see what's wrong. The error message is usually pretty detailed and useful.

Comment: Also, paste the JSON you get into app.quicktype.io to get a very reasonable first version of the structs you need

Comment: @Gereon thanks! I have updated my question to show the error i received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Following is the correct structure**

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let songResponse = try decoder.decode(SongResponse.self, from: jsonData)
    let songInfos = songResponse.result ?? []
    completion(.success(songInfos))
}catch{
    completion(.failure(.canNotProcessData))
}
```

// Models

```
struct SongResponse: Decodable {
    var success: Bool?
    var result: [SongInfo]?
} 

struct SongInfo: Decodable {
    var track: String?
    var artist: String?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To mirror the json structure, you have to change the key in `SongResponse`.

```
struct SongResponse: Decodable {
    var result: [SongInfo]
}
```